# How can I carry over parent breadcrumbs to children in a recursive function for building a PHP array tree of categories?

Tags: php, recursion, categories, breadcrumbs

I have a query that pulls all food categories, a function that iterates recursively to create a tree, and finally another recursive function that flattens it while adding a depth indicator.

The recursion works fine.  I am having difficulty passing the parent breadcrumbs down to each children.  There must be a crumb for each level, even the last.

Although crumb accumulation requires the current node be for a specific parent, the function carries over all past crumbs somehow, even crumbs from children of other parents.  The rest of the structure abides by the parent/children relationship.  I cannot see why the breadcrumbs don't.

a small sample of the query results

```
$QueryResults = array
    (
        0 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 42
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => 1
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Alcoholic'
                            )
                    )
            ),
        1 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 39
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => 4
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Beef'
                            )
                    )
            ),
        2 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 1
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => NULL
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Beverages'
                            )
                    )
            ),
        3 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 44
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => 1
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Carbonated'
                            )
                    )
            ),
        4 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 46
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => 1
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Coffee'
                            )
                    )
            ),
         5 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 4
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => NULL
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Meats'
                            )
                    )
            ),
         6 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 44
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => 4
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Processed Meats'
                            )
                    )
            ),
         7 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 45
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => 44
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Luncheon Meats'
                            )
                    )
            ),
        8 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 7
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => 4
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Pork'
                            )
                    )
            ),
        9 => array
            (
                'Fields' => array
                    (
                        0 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'id',
                                'Value' => 8
                            ),
                        1 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'parent_id',
                                'Value' => 4
                            ),
                        2 => array
                            (
                                'FieldName' => 'name',
                                'Value' => 'Poultry'
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
;
```

here's my attempt at processing the database query results (the tree flattens after this completes).

```
function buildTree($elements, $parentId, $crumbs) {
  $branch = array();
  
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['Fields'][1]['Value'] == $parentId) {
      
      $currentCrumbs[] = array('Fields' => array(0 => array('FieldName' => 'id','Value' => $element['Fields'][0]['Value']),1 => array('FieldName' => 'Crumb','Value' => $element['Fields'][2]['Value'])));
      
      if (is_array($crumbs)) { // lower levels
        $combinedCrumbs = array_merge($crumbs, $currentCrumbs);
      } else { // top level
        $combinedCrumbs = $currentCrumbs;
      }
      $element['BreadCrumbs'] = $combinedCrumbs;
      
      $children = buildTree($elements, $element['Fields'][0]['Value'], $combinedCrumbs);
      if ($children) {
        $element['SubGroups'] = $children;
      }
      $branch[] = $element;
      
    }
  }
  
  return $branch;
}
```

This part of the database is like this, but other parts are more layers deep:

- Beverages

  - Alcoholic
  - Carbonated

The full structure takes a lot of space to display, so this is just one node containing "carbonated" beverages.  It correctly carries over the "Beverages", but then it also contains the crumb from "Alcoholic" leaf which is not a part of the "Carbonated" chain.  I don't know how the crumb from the "Alcoholic" instance of this function made its way into the "Carbonated" chain of function instances.  The rest of the tree builds correctly.  It's not a local problem--"Beverages" also makes its way into the "Meats" top level node.

Current behavior (notice how "Alcoholic" is present):

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [Fields] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [FieldName] => id
                        [Value] => 44
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [FieldName] => parent_id
                        [Value] => 1
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [FieldName] => name
                        [Value] => Carbonated
                    )
            )
        [BreadCrumbs] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Fields] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => id
                                        [Value] => 1
                                    )
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => Crumb
                                        [Value] => Beverages
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Fields] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => id
                                        [Value] => 42
                                    )
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => Crumb
                                        [Value] => Alcoholic
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [Fields] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => id
                                        [Value] => 44
                                    )
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => Crumb
                                        [Value] => Carbonated
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

Expected Behavior:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [Fields] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [FieldName] => id
                        [Value] => 44
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [FieldName] => parent_id
                        [Value] => 1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [FieldName] => name
                        [Value] => Carbonated
                    )
            )
        [BreadCrumbs] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Fields] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => id
                                        [Value] => 1
                                    )
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => Crumb
                                        [Value] => Beverages
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Fields] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => id
                                        [Value] => 44
                                    )
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [FieldName] => Crumb
                                        [Value] => Carbonated
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

I Understand this structure is more verbose and deeper than it probably needs to be if it were associative instead of indexed, but for reasons not related and in ways not obvious, it is what it is.

I have a separate failed effort on the flattened array with its parent_id intact and a depth indicator added, but a solution there would work too.

How can i adjust this such that only the crumbs for the given chain accumulate?

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, this appears to be a typo question where you merely need to remove the unneeded `[]` in the `$currentCrumbs` declaration.  Why isn't `$crumbs` declared as an empty array in the function signature?

Comment: Good catch @mickmackusa, I meant to set both $parentid and $crumbs to null initially.  i was passing nulls temporarily and forgot to change it.

I didn't know i was only a line or 2 off.  I kept scratching my head at this one.

Comment: I never set a parameter to `null` if it can be an array.  Just default it to `array $crumbs = []` in the signature.  You can instantly `array_merge()` with an empty array -- you can't do that with a `null`.  I would not use that `is_array()` check.  How are you calling this recursive function (we should understand the full [mcve].)

Comment: thanks for the point on setting it to empty array instead.  i changed them to =[], removed is_array() and it merged them all the same, even though some where empty.  it takes the query result as an input directly and saves it into a new variable.  i read the link and will remember this in the future.

Comment: How are you calling your function to produce this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked into it and this worked for me:

```
function buildTree($elements, $parentId, $crumbs) {
  $branch = array();
    
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['Fields'][1]['Value'] == $parentId) {

      $currentCrumbs = array(array('Fields' => array(0 => array('FieldName' => 'id','Value' => $element['Fields'][0]['Value']),1 => array('FieldName' => 'Crumb','Value' => $element['Fields'][2]['Value']))));


      if (is_array($crumbs)) { // lower levels
        $combinedCrumbs = combineArrays($crumbs, $currentCrumbs);
      } else { // top level
        $combinedCrumbs = $currentCrumbs;
      }
      $element['BreadCrumbs'] = $combinedCrumbs;

      $children = buildTree($elements, $element['Fields'][0]['Value'], $combinedCrumbs);
      if ($children) {
        $element['SubGroups'] = $children;
      }
      $branch[] = $element;

    }
  }

  return $branch;
}
```

The main problem was that you have appended elements to `$currentCrumbs`, like

```
$currentCrumbs[]= ...
```

So, when there are more elements to process, that is, there are more than one siblings, such as in the case of Alcoholic and Carbonated, whose parent is Beverages, at the first step Alcoholic is "added" to a non-existing array, that is, a new array is being created with a single element, Alcoholic. Then, when it is proceeding to the second step, that is, to Carbonated, then Alcoholic is already in `$currentCrumbs` and `Carbonated` is added to it, resulting in an array of two elements.

Instead, I'm creating a new array at every iteration of the loop.

Also, I wrapped an array around the array and separated the merging. The result was a success:

[image]

Comment: Huh? Where does `combineArrays()` come from?  There is only 1 mention of that mystery function on this page -- in your answer, which means that it is never defined.

Comment: Odd, I missed this.  I kept array_merge() in the working example.

Comment: @mickmackusa sorry about that. I forgot to paste it into the answer and I removed the file since then. But basically it was doing some validations and defensive programming and then merging the two arrays. It basically separated the array merging and made the code safer regarding different possible inputs. You can use `array_merge` instead. If you strongly prefer this function to be in this answer, then I can reproduce it.